# Curved SVG textpath doesn't render unicode text/font properly on Apple devices

Tags: svg, unicode, rendering

I am trying to render unicode text (Telugu) on a curved SVG textPath. Text on textPath is not rendered properly with textPath on apple devices (Safari as well as Chrome), characters do not cluster as expected, where as text using  rendered properly.

Working rendering on my Linux OS with Firefox and Chrome
[image: Working rendering on my Linux OS with Firefox and Chrome]

Rendering issue on my iPad, iPhone with Chrome as well as Safari

[image: Rendering issue on my iPad, iPhone with Chrome as well as Safari]

Following fiddle shows my SVG code

https://jsfiddle.net/SudhakarA/o7w3f4gL/1/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
      <![CDATA[
      @font-face {
        font-family: "Noto Serif Telugu";
        font-weight: 100 900;
        font-style: normal italic;
# src: url(data:font/ttf;base64, <removed base64 data to keep code simple. Same can be viewed in jsfiddle link> );
      }

      text {
        font-family: Noto Serif Telugu;
      }
      ]]>
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path id="MyPath" stroke="lightblue" fill="none" d="M 10,50 C 100,0 200,100 250,50" />
  <text>
    <textPath href="#MyPath">Text Path: తెలుగు బాషలో రాసిన సందేశము</textPath>
  </text>
  <text x="20" y="80" font-family="Noto Serif Telugu">Text: తెలుగు బాషలో రాసిన సందేశము</text>
</svg>
```

Looking forward for your valuable inputs.

Comment: Thank you for quick response @RobertLongson. I have reported this behavior to Webkit via bug id [266832](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=266832)